# I want to print 90,000 toString lines to a TextField in JavaFX. It's taking super long. Any fixes?

Tags: performance, javafx, linked-list, iterator, big-o

I'm using an iterator to iterate through a Linked List of 90,000 Book Objects. Each of them have titles, ISBNs, authors and prices.

In my GUI, I have a text field, and a button which would display these 90,000 Books.toString() in the text field. The user can search for a book, remove a book, or update fields in the book, so I feel like the user should be able to see all the books and all their fields.

The problem is, this takes way too long, I get the beach ball of death and it never loads. When I change the for loop to 10 or 1000, it works fine. Must be an O(n^2), right?

Or is there some other problem?
Thank you.

```
@FXML
    void refreshListButtonPressed(ActionEvent event) {
        listBooksTextArea.clear();
        bookbag.myIter.reset();
        for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        listBooksTextArea.appendText(bookbag.myIter.getCurrent().getData().toString() + 
"\n");
        bookbag.myIter.nextLink();
        if(bookbag.myIter.atEnd()) {
            listBooksTextArea.appendText(bookbag.myIter.getCurrent().getData().toString()+ 
"\n");
            }
        }
        }
```

Ideally, I wouldn't even use a for loop, I'd use while (!bookbag.myIter.atEnd()), but the for loop proves to me the code works and the size or efficiency is the issue.

Comment: Use a `ListView` or `TableView`

Comment: @James_D Oh, wow, thank you! Why did that seem to work?

Comment: Those are “virtualized” controls. UI elements are only created for the visible items and reused as the user scrolls. With a `TextArea` the text node is created and laid out for the entire text.

Comment: Note you could probably speed up the text area by concatenating the text into a `StringBuilder` first, and then calling `setText` with the result, but `ListView` or `TableView` are the recommended approach.

Comment: Whenever you experience performance problems, get yourself a decent profiler tool and have it tell you what line of code / method call consumes your CPU time. There's no need for guesswork, there are tools.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is inefficient in a couple of different ways:

1. The `TextArea` stores the text as a `String`, which is an immutable object. Consequently, each time you call `appendText(...)` a new String is created, by copying the existing characters plus the new characters to a new string object. Since the size of the string grows essentially linearly on each iteration, this becomes an `O(n^2)` operation.
2. The `TextArea` creates a UI node for the entire text. UI nodes are generally quite expensive, and here you are creating a huge node to lay out, style, and display all 90,000 lines of text, the vast majority of which are not visible on the screen at any given time.

You can at least partially fix the first by concatenating the string in a `StringBuilder`, and then setting the text of the `TextArea` once, though this will not fix the second issue.

The preferred approach here is to use a *virtualized control*, such as a `ListView` or `TableView`. These controls create a limited number of cells (one per row in the case of a `ListView`, one per column per row in the case of a `TableView`), essentially creating cells only for the visible data. As the user scrolls around, cells are reused to display new data. This greatly enhances performance.

Additionally, these controls probably allow for a better interaction between your UI and your actual data. Using a `TableView`, each row would represent a `Book` object, and each cell in the row a property of that object. If you make your table editable, you can validate changes to each cell, i.e. on a property-by-property basis. Using a text area, you would need to carefully parse the changes to the text to make sure the result was a valid list of books.

I would generally recommend working through a tutorial on `TableView`, e.g. [this one](https://code.makery.ch/library/javafx-tutorial/part2/). In brief, create a `Book` class using [JavaFX Properties](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/binding/jfxpub-binding.htm). Create a `TableView<Book>` and configure the columns to point to appropriate properties using the `setCellValueFactory(...)` method. You can make the data editable by supplying, for example, a [`TextFieldTableCell`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/14/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/cell/TextFieldTableCell.html) in the cell factory for the column. Then simply add your `Book` instances to the table's `items` list.